# ESLint 'The extension for the file (.vue) is non-standard' error

Tags: vue.js, eslint, tsconfig, eslint-plugin-vue

When run `eslint --ext \".js,.ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .` script using `npm run lint`, the following error occurs.

```
/(somethingSomething...)/Test.vue
  0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: components/Test.vue.
The extension for the file (.vue) is non-standard. You should add "parserOptions.extraFileExtensions" to your config
```

I'm using `vue-eslint-parser` and `eslint-plugin-vue` as devDependencies. And `.eslintrc.js` contains

```
...
extends: [
...
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json'
  },
  plugins: [
    'html',
    'vue',
    'jest'
  ],
...
```

as described in manual. And `tsconfig.eslint.json` is

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.js", "./**/*.vue","test/**/*.js"]
}
```

Why these errors occur, and how can I use lint for Vue?